# How to keep non-breaking space in cross-references

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I use cross-references to figures in Microsoft Word 2010. I manually include non-breaking spaces between Figure and number, e.g., `Figure[non-breaking space]1.1` if needed at the end of a line (which prevents `1.1` from being printed on the next line).

If I update the references with <kbd>F9</kbd> (i.e.,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>F9</kbd>), the non-breaking spaces are lost.

Is there a way to force MS Word to keep these non-breaking spaces in cross-references?

Answer (score 1):

When you update the reference, your manual edit of the cross-reference will be overwritten. You can't do anything about it.

You should include the non-breaking space in your figure subtitle. Do it generally in all subtitles, it doesn't hurt. These non-breaking spaces will be included inside the cross-references and hence you don't have to do anything manually if such a cross reference happens to be moved near the end of a line.

I disrecommend to use the the built-in creator of captions ("Caption dialog"). Rather use the "[method of the pros](https://superuser.com/questions/399771/adding-many-cross-reference-in-ms2007-2010-is-very-tedious/1454493#1454493)":

> Figure<kbd>non-breaking space</kbd>{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC }<kbd>Tab</kbd>This figure shows XYZ.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I could find is to manually add a non-breaking space between the label ("Figure" in this case) and the figure number of your figure caption. Refer to the figure below where I have shown the paragraph marks to indicate where I have added the non-breaking space (°). The non-breaking space will now remain in your cross-reference when you update.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think  you are changing the space character in the cross-reference.

If you change the space character in the Figure caption itself it should "stick" (That's what happens here). A table of Figures should still generate OK, but with the non-breaking space characters instead of ordinary spaces.

But I don't think you can insert a non-breaking space via the Caption dialog, so if you want to make insertion relatively easy, you should modify one caption and make an Autotext from it.

Answer (score 0):

When making caption to figure check "Exclude label from caption" option.
It will create caption with only the number.
Then insert manually the word "Figure" with "non-breaking space" before created caption.
Now when you create cross-reference to this figure the caption will be with "non-breaking space" even after refreshing.

Comment: This looks like a lot of work compared with simply putting the non-breaking space in the caption to start with.